# how to create two different nameSpaces in one same nameSpace avoiding covering the first one?

Tags: javascript, namespaces

i want to use two string(which i don`t know their content) to create two nameSpace.And i don`t want to create a new one if the nameSpace exists.
here is my code:

```
function createNameSpace(nameSpace)
{
    var spaceArr = nameSpace.split(".");
    var curSpace = window;

    //judge if this nameSpace exists.
    var i;
    for(i in spaceArr)
    {
        curSpace = curSpace[spaceArr[i]];
        if(curSpace)
            window.alert("nameSpace1:" + nameSpace + "\ncurSpace do exists:" + curSpace + "\ni:" + i + "\nspaceArr[i]:" + spaceArr[i] + "|");
        else
        {
            curSpace = {};
            window.alert("nameSpace1:" + nameSpace + "\ncurSpace not found:" + curSpace + "\ni:" + i + "\nspaceArr[i]:" + spaceArr[i] + "|");
            break;
        }
    }

    //now curSpace must have been created.
    i++;
    //window.alert("nameSpace2:" + nameSpace + "\ni:" + i + "\nspaceArr.length:" + spaceArr.length);
    //create the nameSpace
    for(;i < spaceArr.length; i++)
    {
        //window.alert("nameSpace2:" + nameSpace + "\ni:" + i + "\nspaceArr.length:" + spaceArr.length);
        if(i == 0)
        {
            window[spaceArr[i]] = {};
            curSpace = window[spaceArr[i]];
        }
        else
        {
            //window.alert("nameSpace3:" + nameSpace + "\ncurSpace[spaceArr[i]]:" + curSpace[spaceArr[i]]);
            curSpace[spaceArr[i]] = {};
            curSpace = curSpace[spaceArr[i]];
        }
    }
    return curSpace;
}
```

the problem is,if i send"myTest.myNameSpace"and"myTest.monaNameSpace" into this func,it all alert"curSpace not found",which should be "curSpace do exists:" when i send "myTest.monaNameSpace" . i can`t tell where the mistakes are,can someone tell me?

Answer (score 0):

I think your algorithm is a little to complex. I refactored it a little and added a test to it and verified it worked in the console. I have also written this code several times, so i am pretty sure i have hit your requirements

```
function createNameSpace(nameSpace)
{
    var spaceArr = nameSpace.split(".");
    var curSpace = window;

    //judge if this nameSpace exists.
    var i = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < spaceArr.length; i++)
    {
        var next = spaceArr[i];
        console.log(curSpace, next);
        if(curSpace[next] == undefined)
        {
            curSpace[next] = {};
            curSpace = curSpace[next]
        }
        else
        {
            curSpace = curSpace[next];
        }
    }

    return curSpace;
}
createNameSpace("myTest.myNameSpace");
console.log(myTest.myNameSpace);
myTest.myNameSpace.myName = "Leat Hakkor";
createNameSpace("myTest.monaNameSpace");
console.log(myTest.monaNameSpace);
console.log(myTest.myNameSpace.myName);
```